# TINYMCE configuration to get structured input

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce

Teachers need to enter questions and there are four types of questions. 'MCQ's where there is one stem and five options and an answer. In 'Matching', 7 question and answers. In 'SAQ', where there is a question and answer both like paragraphs. I need to get input defined by this structure. users can't submit an MCQ with 4 or 6 options and so on for each. Each question should recieve such structured input based on the type of the question. Inputs could be pasted text from word may contain format, images etc limited to the strucutre. How can I handle this?